# IIS errors when configuring DSC pull server with WMF 5

Tags: powershell, iis, dsc

I have been trying to configure a pull server with 2012 r2 and WMF5. I used these instructions which worked fine until validating the IIS server:

http://www.systemcentercentral.com/day-1-intro-to-powershell-dsc-and-configuring-your-first-pull-server/

Going to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080:PSDSCPullServer.svc

Gives me an error: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Not 100% sure, but this appears to be this bug:

https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11088528-devices-edb-does-not-exists-when-wmf5-is-installed

Looks like this user got past this: "When WMF5 is already installed, and the DSC Pull Server is created, the web configuration must be reconfigured to utilize the devices.mdb database and the System.Data.OleDb provider instead of the ESENT provider and the devices.edb database."

Can somebody tell me how to reconfigure IIS to utilize the devices.mdb database and the System.Data.OleDb provider?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has fixed the issue:

[Powershell DSC Pull Server throws internal error - Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252635/powershell-dsc-pull-server-throws-internal-error-microsoft-isam-esent-interop)

I have now been able to get an xml formatted response from IIS and have gone on to configure my first node... still I'm not sure if I've missed anything since there are two new IIS sites I see - PSDSCPullServer and PSDSComplianceServer and I only altered PSDSCPullServer...